# Flutter NavigationBar Ignores my background Color

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Why does my BottomNavigationBar ignore the background color I choose:

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: BlocBuilder<NavbarCubit, NavbarState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return BottomNavigationBar(
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.green,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            //fixedColor: Colors.blue,
            currentIndex: state.index,
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.fastfood_outlined),
                label: "Hungrig?",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.sports_gymnastics), label: "Sport!"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.do_not_disturb_on_total_silence), label: "Focus!"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.construction), label: "Gadgets"),
            ],
```

This is the result:

[image: Picture]

I tried to implement a `Theme` on it and I realized it was ignoring the color I added in the `ThemeData`. After that I tried to hard coded the color, but it still did not display the color I chose. How can I make it use the color I want?

Comment: Set the type to type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed inside the BotttomNavigationBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `BottomNavigationBar's type` not `fixed` you need to change `canvasColor` by wrap the `BottomNavigationBar` with `Theme` like this:

```
Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      canvasColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    ),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.green,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
      currentIndex: 1,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.fastfood_outlined),
          label: "Hungrig?",
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.sports_gymnastics), label: "Sport!"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.do_not_disturb_on_total_silence),
            label: "Focus!"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.construction), label: "Gadgets"),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

but if your purpose is use fixed `BottomNavigationBar` you need to set that(as @OzanTaskiran mentioned in comment) like this and then it will work:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.green,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,// <--- add this
    //fixedColor: Colors.blue,
    currentIndex: 1,
    showUnselectedLabels: false,
    items: const [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.fastfood_outlined),
        label: "Hungrig?",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.sports_gymnastics), label: "Sport!"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.do_not_disturb_on_total_silence),
          label: "Focus!"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.construction), label: "Gadgets"),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Ah okay, intersting didnt know that. Worked out, thanks a lot. No I liked it without the fixed option more